# does anyone know why this keeps crashing, it started crashing when i added in the average

Tags: c++, average

does anyone know why this keeps crashing, it started crashing when i added in the average. if anyone know plz help im new to codeing and this is complex to me thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int integers;
    int average;
    int sum = 0;
    vector<int> numbers;
    cout << "Please enter in integers and enter 0 to stop: ";
    while (cin >> integers) {
        if (integers == 0) {
            sum = sum + integers;
            break;
        }
        numbers.push_back(integers);

    }
    int y = numbers.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
        cout << numbers[i] << " ";
        average = (sum / integers);
        cout << "The average is: " << average << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like time to crack open the debugger!  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Look at the values of `sum` and `integers` when you calculate `average`.

Comment: Why are you doing the average in a loop?  You already have the sum and you know the size of the vector.  The average is just the sum divided bu the size of the vector.

Comment: Remember that the first time code hits a return it returns..

Comment: It looks like `integers` would be 0 at the end of the first loop (unless your input fails). Additionally, sum looks to always be 0, since you only add `integers` to it when `integers` is zero. That means `average = 0/0;`. This problem would have been much quicker to solve with a debugger than by posting here.

Comment: Did you mean to put the last 3 lines of the for loop inside the loop? They look like they should be after the loop instead of part of the loop.

Comment: You probably want to use `average = (sum / numbers.size())` but after the loop not in the loop

Comment: @drescherjm I did a rollback on that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the time you reach your `for` loop the `integers` variable has a value of `0`. In this statement:

```
average = (sum / integers);
```

you are dividing by `0` thus causing [undefined behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) and/or exception depending on the implementation. That being said you are not calculating the `sum` nor the `average` correctly.

Comment: `sum` is also 0, so the expression is 0/0. Same effect, of course. +1.

Comment: thanks for the help and stack overflow is hating on me now saying that "the community did not take your question well"

Comment: @matt Try not to take it too personally. Nobody "_hates you_". Read the links in the yellow box. I have questions of my own that were closed. No big deal. Take what you can from the experience to better your future inquiries.